# Programmatically select an item in Dropdown in Semantic-UI-React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I created a Dropdown list using Semantic-UI-React to let the user select colors.

[image]

The code is as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const colorOptions = [{
  text: 'red',
  value: 'red'
}, {
  text: 'blue',
  value: 'blue'
}, {
  text: 'custom',
  value: 'custom'
}];

const Foo = () => (
  <Dropdown
    placeholder='color'
    search
    selection
    options={colorOptions} />
)

export default Foo
```

Suppose that the current selected color is red. Now the user clicks on `custom`. Then a dialog will show`` up with more colors. And there are two buttons in the dialog. OK and Cancel.

What I want is that, when the user clicks on `Cancel`, the selected color would revert back to the previous one, `red`, instead of `custom`. Could it be done with Semantic-UI-react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `state` for that.

*I'm assuming you have another component that is rendering your `Foo` component (since you paste its code as a stateless function)*

1. Use `onChange` in your `Dropdown` component, so you keep track of the current value. Should you need more info about how `onChange` works check their [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown).

For example:

```
const Foo = (onChange, value) => (
  <Dropdown
    placeholder='color'
    search
    selection
    options={colorOptions}
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
  />
)
```

2. on every `onChange`, save this value on state and also keep a copy of the previous value. Since `setState` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) you can easily do this as:

Example:

```
handleChange(event, data) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    previousValue: prevState.value,
    value: data
  }))
}
```

3. When you click "Cancel" button simply revert the Dropdowns's value to the previous one.

Example:

```
onCancel() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    value: prevState.previousValue
  }))
}
```

4. on `render` always pass `value` to `Foo` component

Example:

```
<Foo onChange={handleChange} value={this.state.value} ... />
```